# 2d array wont <br> in javascript

Tags: javascript

i try to get this 2d array writen into my webpage. it does write it on my webpage but not underneath eachother like in the var in my javascript file, what am i doing wrong? do i need to change something in my loop because for some reason the if won't work[image]

```
 var zaal1 =

 [

 [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,
  0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,
  0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,
  0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,
  0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,
  0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,
  0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,
  0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,
  0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,
  0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,
  0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,
  0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
  ]


 for (var i = 0; i < zaal1.length; i++) {

    for (var j = 0; j < zaal1[i].length; j++) {
     document.write(zaal1);

  } 

    if ( ( j + 1 ) % 30 == 0 )
      document.write( "<br />" );
}
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the concept of a 2D array. Shouldn't each of the "lines" in the array be its own sub-array? As it is now you have a "1 by some-large-number" 2D array.

Comment: @Biffen I already changed it to :         [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0] ty anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things here.

The first is that you're writing the full `zaal1` variable to the page instead of the offsets created via `i` and `j`.

The second is that your `if` statement that outputs the `<br />` is outside of inner-loop that is based on `j`. Try moving it inside like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < zaal1.length; i++) {

    for (var j = 0; j < zaal1[i].length; j++) {
        document.write(zaal1[i][j]);

        if ( ( j + 1 ) % 30 == 0 ) {
            document.write( "<br />" );
        }
    } 

}
```

However, that's just based on the idea that you want 30 values on each line. It may make more sense to break up your array into individual lines:

```
var zaal1 = [
    [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]
];

for (var i = 0; i < zaal1.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < zaal1[i].length; j++) {
        document.write(zaal1[i][j]);
    }
    document.write('<br />');
}
```

Comment: Yes that works, but than it will duplicate the whole array a lot times, and i'm trying to get it only 1 time (just as how it is in the javascript in the description). Do you have any idea?

Comment: You need to fix the `document.write` as well and only output `zaal1[i][j]` - see my answer below...

Comment: Thank you very much, i've just started javascript so im still learning, was trying to get this done for 4 hours now!

Comment: @BartFokker Ah, my bad - missed the indexes =P. Updated to include the `i` and `j` offsets. Let me know if that works better now?

Comment: @newfurniturey it works perfect thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

Your `<br />` condition needs to be inside the inner loop and the `document.write` outputs the whole array instead of only one value:

```
for (var i = 0; i < zaal1.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < zaal1[i].length; j++) {
        document.write(zaal1[i][j]); // only output one number
        if ( ( j + 1 ) % 30 == 0 ) document.write( "<br />" ); // put this inside your inner loop
    } 
}
```